# Where can I find Solana's price at each epoch?

Tags: rewards, epoch

I need to know what the sol price at each epoch in 2023. I'm trying to calculate my taxes on my solana staking rewards. I used solscan.io to see the rewards I got at each epoch, but I need to know the price to accurately calculate my taxes. I know I could find the time of each epoch and check the sol chart, but I don't want to manually do that a bunch of times.